# Unpacking of list in function but not needed when its done with MAP()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary, iterable-unpacking

```
def ups(*name):
    for n in name:
        a=n.upper()

    return a
lis=["lan","ona"]
m=list(map(ups,lis))
print(m)
```

Here in the map I have not done unpacking of the list, but the same in case of function call for without Map(), (eg) like `ups(*lis)` is must, why is that?

Learning, Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is the code meant to do? What isn't working?

Comment: My code works fine, but when I call a function I use function (*args) but not using *args while doing map. Was just curious to know why map doesn't need list unpacking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [ksourav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58612512/10197418),

- In [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
  you find that `map(function, iterable, ...)` "Return[s] an iterator that applies function to
  **every item of iterable**, yielding the results". As ksourav points out
  in his answer, the items you pass are strings and thus iterables
  themselves - so the function just returns the last letter in
  uppercase, like

```py
s = 'lan'
for char in s:
    print(char.upper())
# L
# A
# N
```

- What * does (in this case) is turning the argument (=string) passed into a 1-element tuple -
  you now iterate over the `tuple` and not the individual elements of
  the string anymore. This is why here, your function returns
  the whole word in uppercase letters, like

```py
t = ('lan',)
for element in t:
    print(element.upper())
# LAN
```

- By the way, a more readable way of writing your function could imho be

```py
m = list(map(lambda x: x.upper(), lis))
# or even better
m = [s.upper() for s in lis]
```

Comment: Thanks :) Yes everywhere they used list comprehension or lambda map solution. I just wanted to try and see how we pass a full function itself :) Now my doubts are clear

Comment: a good way to learn, I get your point! btw., unpacking can also be useful the other way round, if you have a function `func` with n positional arguments and a list `L` of n elements that you want to pass to the function, you could do `func(*L)`

Comment: Out of curiosity, instead of list, can map use dict also for iteration?

Comment: Dicts have an `__iter__` method, so in principle, you can. Can't think of a good use in combination with `map` right now, but maybe there is... give it a try ;-)

Answer (score 0):

star(*)args means variable number of arguments.so basically your fuction can take variable number of arguments.On the other hand map function takes a function and a list as argument and the function is called on each element of the list that was passed as argument.so If you don't use "*" in the function which you have defined, then it will take one sting in the lis(as you are passing in to the map function) and iterate over it and return the only last letter of each string in uppercase.Because for loop will iterate over the element passed but return only the last element as you are returning only a.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification :)